# Question related to the construction of product measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am learning about product measures and I was stuck on a detail of the proof. I would appreciate any assistance!

Suppose we have a measure spaces $(X_i, M_i, \mu_i), i=1, ..., N$, that are complete and $\sigma$-finite. We call sets measurable rectangles, if it has the following form
$$
A_1 \times ... \times A_N,
$$ 
where each $A_i \in M_i$.

Let $M_0$ denote the collection of sets that are finite disjoint union of measurable rectangles. Then $M_0$ turns out to be an algebra of subsets of $X_1 \times ... \times X_N$. I am having hard time seeing how $M_0$ is an algebra. Could someone please explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to [prove that it is closed](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebra_of_sets) in respect to finite union, intersection and complement. The union is pretty clear (it is the definition of $M_0$), the [complement doesn't seem to be very difficult too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra)... As for the intersection, I think that you should first analyse an intersection of two rectangles. And then you decompose the intersection of a union of such rectangles into the union of intersections.